# JBoss cannot find class for javax.management.DynamicMBean

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I am currently in the process of rearranging application jars so that my application can run smoothly on Websphere as well as JBoss with minimal changes.

With Webshpere's hierarchical class loading, everything works fine. But JBoss is creating lots of issues with its modular loading, with exceptions like -

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "javax.management.DynamicMBean" from [Module from local module loader

Since this class is part of JDK 6, should JBoss not pick it up automatically? Does anyone know any solution to this?

I am using JBoss AS 7.3 with JDK 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by adding a dependency on javax.api in module.xml for one of my custom jboss modules.